# Can an Orthodox doctor ask a not-yet-religious Jewish doctor to take his shabbos rounds?

Tags: shabbat, medicine, lifnei-iver

Can an Orthodox doctor ask a not-yet-religious Jewish colleague to exchange Shabbos hospital rotations?

Comment: Is a not-yet-religious Jew less bound by the laws (or less able to save someone's life)?

Comment: Ooh. I remember a machlokes amongst the Israeli Rabbis if you should rather use an irreligious  car service to take you to the hospital. One said yes. And one said no as the allowance of chilul shabbos for pikuach nefesh etc is only for one who actually keeps Shabbos, not for one who brazenly desecrates it. I think the question was regarding driving a woman in labor to the hospital, if that matters.

Comment: Machloket Rav moshe feinstein and Rav Shlomo zalman aurbach

Comment: See nishmat Abraham....

Comment: Isn't this a bit like asking if a law abiding citizen can ask a criminal to commit a crime for him?

Answer (score 1):

Shemiras Shabbos 40:27 says that the orthodox doctor should not exchange with the non-religious doctor as the latter may come to transgress shabbos.

Comment: I suspect you mean "in ways unnecessary to save lives", but if so, you should add that.

Comment: I was aware of this when I wrote my answer. Pekuach nefesh docheh shabbos is a given and applies to everyone in all cases so why would one assume otherwise in this specific case?

Comment: Rav Feinstein disagree.